# Command line building of a vcxproj for visual studio 2013 and visual studio 2010

Tags: command, devenv

I have certain  VS2010 and VS2013 C++ projects that I want to compile using command line.The command I followed was :

```
*devenv.exe "C:\Geek\toDo\MyTester\MyTester.vcxproj" /projectconfig Release
devenv.exe "C:\Geek\toDo\MyTester\MyTester.vcxproj" /p:Configuration=Release /command Build*
```

-->With the above commands , it opens up IDE with MyTester project but does not compile the project.

I wanted to build this project from command line itself i.e., it must open up the IDE and start compiling as soon as this devenv command is executed.
Is it possible with DEVENV's command line switches ?

Comment: Any help in this regard..??

Comment: I found the below command to be working as expected where it compiles the project for me in the IDE : --> COMMAND IS --->"   devenv "C:\Geek\toDo\MyTester\MyTester.vcxproj"  \run   " . Using C++, If I put the same command in a string and run system(string) from c++code...it does not show up anything.